# Action of G_2 on certain 7x7 skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, octonions

I have been working with something related to Goldman bracket for $G_2$ gauge group. There I have something like "$\text{Tr}(M_{\gamma}O_i)$", where $M_{\gamma}$ is a monodromy which takes value in the group $G_2$ (in the fundamental representation) and $O_i, i=1,2,\ldots,7$" are the 7x7 skew-symmetric matrices that can be obtained from the 8x8 matrix representation of left multiplication by octonionic imaginary units deleting the first row and the first column.

My question is the following:
can $M_{\gamma}O_{i}M_{\gamma}^{-1}$ be expressed as a suitable linear combination of the $O_i$'s? The matrices $O_i$'s are given explicitly in my paper:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4519.pdf
(eq. (4.3) p-19)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  This follows from the fact that $G_2$ acts on the octonions via automorphisms.

Let $e_i$, $i=1,\dots,7$ be a choice of 7 imaginary octonion units and let $1$ denote the identity.  Then by definition of the $O_i$, we have that
$$
e_i e_j = \sum_k e_k (O_i)_{kj} - \delta_{ij} 1
$$
where the left-hand side is octonion multiplication.

Let $g \in G_2$.  Since $G_2$ acts on the octonions via automorphisms,
$$
g(e_i) = \sum_j e_j M_{ji}~.
$$
The $M_{ji}$ are the entries of the matrix $M_\gamma$ in the question.

Now apply $g \in G_2$ on the first displayed equation.  On the LHS we have
$$
g(e_i e_j) = g(e_i) g(e_j) = \sum_{k,l} \left(\sum_m e_m (O_k)_{ml} - \delta_{kl} 1\right) M_{ki} M_{lj} = \sum_k (O_k M)_{mj} M_{ki} - \delta_{ij} 1~,
$$
where we have used that $M$ is orthogonal, so that $\sum_{k,l} \delta_{kl} M_{ki} M_{lj} = \delta_{ij}$.  Similarly, on the RHS we find
$$
\sum_{m,k} e_m M_{mk} (O_i)_{kj} - \delta_{ij} 1
$$
using that $g(1) = 1$.

Comparing the two, we find
$$
\sum_{k,l,m} e_m (O_k)_{ml} M_{ki} M_{lj} = \sum_{m,k} e_m M_{mk} (O_i)_{kj}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\sum_k (O_k M)_{mj} M_{ki} = (M O_i)_{mj}
$$
or, finally,
$$
M O_i M^{-1} = \sum_k O_k M_{ki}~.
$$

**Edit**  To answer the comment, there is a coordinate-free proof of this fact, and perhaps I should have written that first.  What is $M O_i M^{-1}$?  It is the matrix of left multiplication by the imaginary octonions (projected to the imaginary octonions) under a $G_2$ change of basis.  But $G_2$ is an automorphism of the octonions, hence it preserves the subspace of imaginary octonions.  Hence $M O_i M^{-1}$ is the matrix  of left multiplication by *some* imaginary octonion unit, whence some linear combination of the $O_i$, since these form a basis.

Comment: I think you have RHS and LHS reveresed. Also, it may be worth to mention that you are using $g(e_i e_j) = g(e_i)g(e_j)$.

Comment: Indeed.  But why do I have LHS and RHS reversed?  The action of $g$ on the LHS of the equation is $g(e_i e_j)$...

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. Everything seems to be in order. Now I just wonder whether there is a coordinate-free proof.

Comment: I've edited with a coordinate-free proof.

Comment: I have another quick query. Do these skew-symmetric matrices $O_i$'s live in the complement of the Lie algebra g_2 in so(7)? Can one construct a closed formula for the multiplications of these matrices $O_i$'s (perhaps by introducing a few other 7x7 matrices, if necessary)?

Comment: That's also true.  The adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{so}(7)$ breaks up under $G_2$ as the adjoint representation and the seven-dimensional irreducible representation.  Since the subspace spanned by the $O_i$ is stable under the adjoint representation (i.e., under conjugation), it has to be isomorphic to the unique seven-dimensional irreducible representation of $G_2$.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill: Actually, your coordinate-free proof seems a bit misleading to me as it suggest (at least to me) that the statement is true also for bigger groups than $G_2$. The problematic sentence is this one: "It is the matrix of left multiplication by the imaginary octonions ..." If one works with the full 8x8 matrices, than indeed the product $MO_iM^{-1}$ is a matrix of the mapping $x \mapsto g(e_i g^{-1}(x))$ but now one has to use the fact that $g$ is automorphism of the octonions to get that this mapping is the same as $x \mapsto g(e_i) x$.

Comment: I tried to estimate the dimension of the orbit of $O_i$. With respect to the full $\mathrm{GL}(7,\mathbb{R})$ action I got a lower bound of 16, so there's no chance for the statement to remain true. For $\mathrm{Spin}(7)$ I got 6.

Comment: It appears very interesting (at least to me) that using the above identity one can prove that objects like $\sum_{i}Tr(M_{\gamma_{1}}O_i)Tr(M_{\gamma_{2}}O_i)$ are gauge invariant, meaning, $\sum_{i}Tr(gM_{\gamma_{1}}g^{-1}O_i)Tr(gM_{\gamma_{2}}g^{-1}O_i)=\sum_{i}Tr(M_{\gamma_{1}}O_i)Tr(M_{\gamma_{2}}O_i)$ for all $g\in G_{2}$. These exotic gauge invariant objects aren't present in the cases of classical Lie groups. One can go steps further to see that observables like $\sum_{i,j}Tr(M_{\gamma_{1}}O_{i}O_{j})Tr(M_{\gamma_{2}}O_i)Tr(M_{\gamma_{3}}O_j)$ are also gauge invariant. How many others?

Comment: @José Figueroa-O'Farrill: Is there an easy way to cite this mathoverflow link in a paper?

Comment: @user78032: Yes, check out this meta question: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/402/394